# Ударение на втором слоге в слове "приведённый"

Tags: орфоэпия

Ударение в слове "привЕденный" на втором слоге или написание без буквы Ё будет считаться грубой ошибкой?

Comment: Словари не разрешают.

Comment: @oleed если вы хотите дать ответ, дайте ответ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это очень грубая ошибка, которая называется **ненормированной речью.**

В причастиях, образованных от глаголы на СТЬ, ЧЬ, ТИ, ударение обычно падает на суффикс ЁНН: *принести  – принесенный, привести  – приведенный.*

Исключений мало, например: *стричь  – стриженный, красть  – краденный, пройти  – пройденный.*

Возможная **причина речевой ошибки**  – это деепричастие *привЕдший*, где ударение падает на Е.